# NullPointerException in Android OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I want an `OnItemClickListener` to send a String from one `Activity` to another. The second `Activity` displays this data in one XML file. I am using an `Intent`, but `LogCat` displays a `NullPointerException`:

```
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidjnetpcaptest/com.example.androidjnetpcaptest.ShowPacketInformationsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at com.example.androidjnetpcaptest.ShowPacketInformationsActivity.onCreate(ShowPacketInformationsActivity.java:19)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-17 19:16:49.611: E/AndroidRuntime(13863):    ... 11 more
```

The `OnItemClickListener` code is:

```
packetsListView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id )
    {
        String[] currentPacketMatrix = packetsList.get( position );
        String selectedInformations = " ";
        for ( int currentPacketMatrixCounter = 0; currentPacketMatrixCounter < currentPacketMatrix.length; currentPacketMatrixCounter++ )
        {
            if ( currentPacketMatrixCounter != 0 && currentPacketMatrixCounter != 1 && currentPacketMatrixCounter != 2 && currentPacketMatrixCounter != 3 && currentPacketMatrixCounter != 4 )
            {
                selectedInformations += currentPacketMatrix[ currentPacketMatrixCounter ] + String.format( "%s", " " );
            }
        }
        Intent nextIntent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, ShowPacketInformationsActivity.class );
        nextIntent.putExtra( "INFORMATIONS", selectedInformations );
        nextIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        startActivity( nextIntent );
    }               
});
```

Comment: packetsList is an ArrayList< String[] >

Comment: can you tell on which activity you are getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I get NullPointerException when I set the selectedInformations in a TextView with setText() method

Comment: What is the error message? Does the stack-trace contain any setText, and if so, on what object/variable?

Comment: please post the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I edited my question with the output of logcat

Comment: Can you please post your second activity. I think there only something going wrong.

Comment: I found the error, in the second activity I didn't initialize one TextView.